# Installing Meteor on an old 32-bit Mac

Tags: meteor

I got myself an old mac to do some front-end work on, but have recently become interested in Meteor and want to install it on it. When attempting to install it i receive the error... "Only 64-bit Intel processors are supported at this time."

I have heard there are ways to manually install it on a 32-bit machine, but I have no idea what to do.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This question belongs in superuser

Comment: Or you could put Ubuntu 32 bit on the old Mac and get going. Since the old Mac can only run up to OS X 10.5 anyway it is doubtful whether there is much benefit in running such an old system for front-end work...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to rebuild Meteor from scratch:

Git clone the meteor repository and run `scripts/generate-dev-bundle.sh`.

You may also need Homebrew to install any dependencies it asks for.

Looking at the source https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/scripts/generate-dev-bundle.sh#L23, it may work if you're on an i386 and not the older powerpc units.